# How would I guarantee random generated data is unique in Python?

Tags: python

```
import random

def generate_broadcast_nodes():
    node_locations = []

    locations = ["barracks","bathroom","bridge","cq","dininghall","dropship","fighterbay","logi","reactor","shiphangar"]

    for i in range(3):
         node_locations.append(locations.pop(random.randint(0,len(locations)-1)))
    return node_locations
```

How can I guarantee that every location generated in this for loop is unique and there are no duplicates?

Comment: `return list(set(node_locations))` will ensure no duplicates

Comment: Don't you already do that? `locations` has completely unique entries and you pop each one meaning you can't get it again.

Comment: @cricket_007 but that may result in a smaller number of elements being selected than expected

Answer (score 2):

Since `locations.pop(random.randint(0,len(locations)-1))` not only returns an element but also removes it from `node_locations` your function already ensures that there are no duplicates in `node_locations` provided `locations` does not contain any.

A better way to generate the random sample would be the use of [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) though.

```
import random

def generate_broadcast_nodes():
    locations = ["barracks", "bathroom", "bridge", "cq", "dininghall",
                 "dropship", "fighterbay", "logi", "reactor", "shiphangar"]

    return random.sample(locations, 3)
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that the list can be cast to a set in the case where it contains duplicates.

Comment: Sure but in this case where the list of possible choices is hardcoded that should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) which by definitions either has an element or not. Your code, however, will always have unique locations as long as the original locations list doesn't contain duplicates. This is because you are [popping](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) the element from `locations` which returns the element (and has the side effect of removing it from the list)

Comment: I don't really like the `set` solution because it has to be enclosed in a non-deterministic loop which could theoretically be infinite. It's also inefficient in the scenario where the pool has a lot of repetitions.